# Tengo un error en este codigo JQuery al intentar direccionar por id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

He hecho el siguiente script para mostrar una imagen según un hipervinculo que el usuario selecciona, el código esta hecho así por varios motivos, el primero es que los href de los hipervinculos se generan en un for y la cantidad depende del usuario, así que no puedo ponerlo por casos porque seria un código muy ineficiente, el código de mi js en principio me proporciona el href que desea el usuario y genera una dirección con el. a través de un getElementById() hago que el img muestre la imagen en esa dirección.

Este es el código:
El href se genera asi, de aqui sale el a.ejercicio:

```
php for ($x = 1; $x <= $num2-2; $x++): ?>
<a class="dropdown-item ejercicio" href="#<?=$i.$x?>">Ejercicio <?= $x ?></a>
<?php endfor; ?>

<script>
        var direccion= "";
        $(a.ejercicio).each(function( index, element ) {
            $(this).click(function {
            direccion= "../packs/" + ($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]) + "/imagen.png";
            direccion=document.getElementById('id-imagen');
            $("#id-imagen").attr("src", direccion).css({"width": "100px"});
            })
        });
</script>
```

Así es como muestro la imagen:

```
<div>
    <img id="id-imagen" alt="">
</div>
```

No me da ningún error, simplemente la imagen que debería aparecerme no me aparece, creo que el problema viene a la hora de generar la dirección pero no lo se.

Comment: Saludos. De momento me surge la siguiente duda ¿que es/tiene `a.ejercicio`?

Comment: es una etiqueta que donde genero los hipervinculos es un tag <a> con id ejercicio

Comment: Primero haces `direccion` igual a una cadena y justo después igual a un elemento.

Comment: Necesito que al poner el id salga la direccion almacenada en la variable direccion y para eso tengo que hacerlo con un getElement no?

Comment: Te sugiero edites y coloques/completes cada elemento; se necesita el valor (en este caso de `a.ejercicio` para evaluar) saber lo que se obtiene y sobre que estas aplicando el `each`; ya esto superado tiene el problema de `direccion` le asignas una cadena (`string`) y luego lo cambia por un objeto `document.getElementById('id-imagen')` que en html que pones solo hay 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cambia esto

```
$(a.ejercicio).each(function( index, element ) {
```

por esto:

```
$(a[class="dropdown-item ejercicio"]).each(function( index, element ) {
```

Lo normal es que no haga nada el script por que `<a>` tiene dos clases, de esta manera cogemos las dos.

Comment: Procura explicar un poco con detalle qué error había y por qué tu solución lo solventa..